# Poincaré serie and partition functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemannian-geometry, group-actions, entropy, statistical-mechanics

Let $(X,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold on which a group $G$ acts properly by isometries $G\curvearrowright X$. We can define the *Poincaré serie* for such action
$$\mathcal{P}_s(G,X)=\sum_{g\in G^*}e^{-sd(x,g.x)}$$
where the sum runs over the elements other that the identity, and the value is independent on the choice of $x\in X$. When we have the fundamental group of $X$ acting in the obvious way on the unversal cover $\widetilde{X}$, the critical exponent of the serie
$$s_0=\inf\{s|\mathcal{P}_s(\Pi(X),\widetilde{X})<\infty\}$$ is called *volume entropy* of $(X,g)$.

In statistical mechanics the *partition function* $Z$ of a system is defined in a completely analogous fashion
$$Z=\sum_i e^{-\beta E_i}$$
where $i$ runs over all microstates of the systems whose energy is $E_i$. These two concept seem analogous, so here is my
**Question:** *Is there a precise way to interpret the Poincaré serie in the statistical mechanical settings? e.g. as the partition function of a system?*

Comment: I don't have much experience with Riemannian geometry. But this does remind of the setting studied in thermodynamic formalism, an area closely related to statistical mechanics and dynamical systems, (see https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~bruin/TF.pdf). The sum you present reminds me of the Ruelle Operator of a subshft, which can be associated to gibbs measures/partition functions. This is usually introduced in the symbolic space but can be extended to  manifolds. One just would need to choose the appropriate potential function. However, in general the Ruelle operator is not independent of $x$.

Comment: In this point of view $x$ is related to a boundary condition of your Gibbs measure.